Convection diffusion equation solve in a rectangular domain
I am trying to solve convection diffusion equation in a rectangular domain with some holes inside. The periphery of these holes are applied to no slip boundary condition. The flow has been initiated as a constant flow from a narrow inlet. Due to concentration gradient this should provide a flow pattern over the time. But I am getting same contour plot for every time step.
   ClearAll[c, t, x, y];

(*Define variables*)
vars = {c[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};

(*Define parameters including diffusion coefficient and advection \
velocity*)
pars = <|"DiffusionCoefficient" -> 2, "AdvectionVelocity" -> {20, 0}|>;

(*Define the convection-diffusion equation*)
eqn = D[c[t, x, y], t] + 
    pars["AdvectionVelocity"] . {D[c[t, x, y], x], D[c[t, x, y], y]} -
     pars["DiffusionCoefficient"] Laplacian[c[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;

(*Initial condition*)
ic = c[0, x, y] == 0;

(*Set the desired ratio of total hole area to the rectangle area*)
desiredRatio = 0.3;

(*Calculate the total area of the rectangle*)
rectangleArea = 4;

(*Calculate the total area of the holes*)
holesArea = desiredRatio*rectangleArea;

(*Generate non-touching holes with areas proportional to the desired \
ratio*)
SeedRandom[123];
numHoles = 20; (*Reduced number of holes for efficiency*)
holeRadii = Sqrt[(holesArea/numHoles)/Pi]*0.8;
holeCenters = RandomReal[{-0.85, 0.85}, {1, 2}];
While[Length[holeCenters] < numHoles, 
 newCenter = RandomReal[{-0.85, 0.85}, 2];
 If[Min[EuclideanDistance[#, newCenter] & /@ holeCenters] > 
   2.4 holeRadii, AppendTo[holeCenters, newCenter]]]

holes = Table[Disk[holeCenters[[i]], holeRadii], {i, numHoles}];

(*Define the spatial domain with holes*)
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], RegionUnion @@ holes];

(*Injection inlet boundary condition on x=-1 in the range-0.2<y<0.2*)
inletBC = 
  DirichletCondition[c[t, x, y] == 10, x == -1 && -0.2 < y < 0.2];

(*Wall boundary conditions for the remaining parts of x=-1*)
wallBC = 
  DirichletCondition[c[t, x, y] == 0, 
   x == -1 && (y <= -0.2 || y >= 0.2)];

(*No-slip boundary conditions for each hole*)
noSlipBCHoles = 
  Table[DirichletCondition[c[t, x, y] == 0, 
    Sqrt[(x - holeCenters[[i, 1]])^2 + (y - holeCenters[[i, 2]])^2] <=
      holeRadii], {i, numHoles}];

(*Combine all boundary conditions*)
bc = {inletBC, wallBC, noSlipBCHoles};

(*Solve the convection-diffusion equation*)
cfun = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic, bc}, 
   c, {t, 0, 25}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];

(*Plot the solution using ContourPlot*)
plot = ContourPlot[cfun[0.02, x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[\[CapitalOmega], {x, y}]]]



Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory Tour now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Check the scaling of your plots. If you add the following into the contour plot options 'PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> {0, 0.005,
0.01, 0.015, 0.02, 0.025}' (of course specifying your own contour levels) you will see that there are changes. The changes are not that easy to see but they are there

In fact if you plot the log of c you will see this much better. As this is a simple mistake I will vote to close this question

For a realistic convection simulation, it could be better to add incompressible viscous flow equations.

Yeasin, would you mind if I take a variation of this example and out it in the Wolfram Documentation?

I'd like to take Alex's approach and fix some issues in it and show a much more concise code.
The mesh generation remains exactly the same and is re-quoted here for convenience.
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(*Set the desired ratio of total hole area to the rectangle area*)
desiredRatio = 0.3;

(*Calculate the total area of the rectangle*)
rectangleArea = 4;

(*Calculate the total area of the holes*)
holesArea = desiredRatio*rectangleArea;

(*Generate non-touching holes with areas proportional to the desired \
ratio*)
SeedRandom[1234];
numHoles = 20; (*Reduced number of holes for efficiency*)
holeRadii = Sqrt[(holesArea/numHoles)/Pi]*0.8;
holeCenters = RandomReal[{-0.85, 0.85}, {1, 2}];
While[Length[holeCenters] < numHoles,
 newCenter = RandomReal[{-0.85, 0.85}, 2];
 If[Min[EuclideanDistance[#, newCenter] & /@ holeCenters] > 
   2.4 holeRadii, AppendTo[holeCenters, newCenter]]]

holes = Table[Disk[holeCenters[[i]], holeRadii], {i, numHoles}];

(*Define the spatial domain with holes*)
\[CapitalOmega] = 
 RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
  RegionUnion @@ holes]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> .001];
 mesh["Wireframe"]


Now, we set up the fluid flow part and we use the predefined system functions, this avoids errors and is much more concise.
(* fluid setup *)
fluidVars = {{u[x, y], v[x, y], p[x, y]}, {x, y}};
fluidPars = <|"MassDensity" -> 1, "DynamicViscosity" -> 10^-2|>;
op = FluidFlowPDEComponent[fluidVars, fluidPars];

Now, I think the boundary conditions Alex uses are not quite correct and in fact you can see ripples at the x==1 outflow. These are typically an indication that the solution is not quite right.
First, we establish the predicates of there the boundary conditions apply; we can re-use this later for the mass transport.
(* general BC predicates *)
inflowPred = x == -1 && (-0.2 <= y <= 0.2);
wallPred = (-1 < x < 
     1) || (x == -1 && (-1 <= y < -0.2 || 0.2 < y <= 1));
outflowPred = x == 1;

Basically, ever part of the boundary needs to be accounted for. Alex uses the predicated 'True'. This can overwrite any other boundary condition and should be avoided. Also Alex sets u and p at the outflow. Typically we only set p. For more information on that you can have a look at the LamniarFlow Monograph that ships with the Mathematica documentation.
We then set up the boundary conditions and solve the PDE:
(* fluid BCs *)
bcsFluid = {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 1, v[x, y] == 0}, 
    inflowPred], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, wallPred], 
   DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, outflowPred]};

{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcsFluid}, {u, v, p}, 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];

If you want higher inflow velocities then you may need to restart the solver; that is also explained in the LamniarFlow Monograph, so I refer you to that.
For visualization I recommend a vector plot, that allows you to quickly see if the flow pattern makes sense.
VectorPlot[{xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 VectorPoints -> Fine]


We proceed in the same way for the mass transport.
(*Define variables*)
mtVars = {c[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};

(*Define parameters including diffusion coefficient and advection \
velocity*)
mtPars = <|"DiffusionCoefficient" -> .2, 
   "MassConvectionVelocity" -> {xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}|>;
op = MassTransportPDEComponent[mtVars, mtPars];
(*Initial condition*)
ic = c[0, x, y] == 0;

For the boundary condition we use exactly the same predicates as we defined above. Again, avoids inconsistencies.
(* BCs *)
mtInletBC = 
  MassConcentrationCondition[inflowPred, mtVars, 
   mtPars, <|"MassConcentration" -> 10|>];
mtWallBC = MassConcentrationCondition[wallPred, mtVars, mtPars];
mtOutflowBC = MassOutflowValue[outflowPred, mtVars, mtPars];

tEnd = 10;
cfun = NDSolveValue[{op == mtOutflowBC, ic, mtInletBC, mtWallBC}, 
  c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]

Last step is then the visualization. Everything is scaled to the min/max values of the solution.
frames = 
  Table[Legended[
    ContourPlot[cfun[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
     PlotRange -> MinMax[cfun["ValuesOnGrid"]], 
     ColorFunction -> 
      ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", MinMax[cfun["ValuesOnGrid"]]}], 
     ContourStyle -> None, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
     Contours -> 10], 
    BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", MinMax[cfun["ValuesOnGrid"]]}, 50, 
     LegendLabel -> Style["C", Opacity[0.6`]]]], {t, 0, tEnd, 1}];

And the animation:
ListAnimate[frames]



(+1) export the format gif Export["test.gif", frames]

@cvgmt, thanks! much better. What confused me was that in the upload dialog the png animation was playing; also my web browser did display it correctly.... but the gif did thanks.

@user21 It could be better to use   PlotRange -> {0,1} instead of PlotRange -> MinMax[cfun["ValuesOnGrid"]] for a proper front visualization.

@user21 Thank you for the boundary condition predicate suggestion to avoid ripples (+1). My code has been updated :)

To solve this problem, we can use Mathematica FEM and incompressible viscous flow model. First, we generate mesh as follows
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(*Set the desired ratio of total hole area to the rectangle area*)
desiredRatio = 0.3;

(*Calculate the total area of the rectangle*)
rectangleArea = 4;

(*Calculate the total area of the holes*)
holesArea = desiredRatio*rectangleArea;

(*Generate non-touching holes with areas proportional to the desired \
ratio*)
SeedRandom[1234];
numHoles = 20; (*Reduced number of holes for efficiency*)
holeRadii = Sqrt[(holesArea/numHoles)/Pi]*0.8;
holeCenters = RandomReal[{-0.85, 0.85}, {1, 2}];
While[Length[holeCenters] < numHoles, 
 newCenter = RandomReal[{-0.85, 0.85}, 2];
 If[Min[EuclideanDistance[#, newCenter] & /@ holeCenters] > 
   2.4 holeRadii, AppendTo[holeCenters, newCenter]]]

holes = Table[Disk[holeCenters[[i]], holeRadii], {i, numHoles}];

(*Define the spatial domain with holes*)
\[CapitalOmega] = 
 RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
  RegionUnion @@ holes]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> .001]; mesh["Wireframe"]


Second, we solve Navier-Stocke's equation in 2D using FEM as (note that code has been updated to avoid ripples at x=1 as user21 recomended)
bcs = {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 10, v[x, y] == 0}, 
    x == -1 && -0.2 < y < 0.2], 
      
       DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, (-1 < x < 1) || (x == -1 && (-1 <= y < -0.2 || 0.2 < y <= 1))], 
       DirichletCondition[{p[x, y] == 1}, x == 1]}; 
op = {Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
           \[Rho]*{{u[x, y], v[x, y]}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y], 
         
    Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
           \[Rho]*{{u[x, y], v[x, y]}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y], 
         
    Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] + Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y]} /. {\[Mu] -> 
     10^(-2), \[Rho] -> 1}; 
pde = op == {0, 0, 0}; {xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
 NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs}, {u, v, p}, 
      Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> 
            {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];

Visualization
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Norm[{xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}], 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20, 
  ContourStyle -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  PlotPoints -> 25, Frame -> False]


Finally, we can solve convection-diffusion problem using flow velocity from the previous step
(*Define variables*)vars = {c[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};

(*Define parameters including diffusion coefficient and advection \
velocity*)
pars = <|"DiffusionCoefficient" -> .2, 
   "AdvectionVelocity" -> {xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}|>;

(*Define the convection-diffusion equation*)
eqn = D[c[t, x, y], t] + 
   pars["AdvectionVelocity"] . {D[c[t, x, y], x], D[c[t, x, y], y]} - 
   pars["DiffusionCoefficient"] Laplacian[c[t, x, y], {x, y}];

(*Initial condition*)ic = c[0, x, y] == 0;
(*Injection inlet boundary condition on x=-1 in the range-0.2<y<0.2*)
inletBC = 
  DirichletCondition[c[t, x, y] == 10, x == -1 && -0.2 < y < 0.2];

(*Wall boundary conditions for the remaining parts of x=-1*)
wallBC = 
  DirichletCondition[c[t, x, y] == 0, 
   x == -1 && (y <= -0.2 || y >= 0.2)];

(*No-slip boundary conditions for each hole*)
zerobc = DirichletCondition[c[t, x, y] == 0, True];

(*Combine all boundary conditions*)
bc = {inletBC, wallBC, zerobc};

(*Solve the convection-diffusion equation*)

cfun1 = NDSolveValue[{eqn == NeumannValue[0, y^2 == 1 || x == 1], ic, 
   bc}, c, {t, 0, 10}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]

We can visualize concentration front using animation
frames = 
  Table[ContourPlot[cfun1[t, x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> {0, .1}, Contours -> 10, 
    ContourStyle -> None, ClippingStyle -> Red, 
    Frame -> False], {t, .05, 5.05, .1}];
ListAnimate[frames]


Update 1. One more stably solution with
SeedRandom[123];
numHoles = 25; 

Flow looks like

For diffusion parameter we take
pars = <|"DiffusionCoefficient" -> 0.1, 
   "AdvectionVelocity" -> {xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}|>;

Visualization concentration in the range (0,1)

